# Business Objects: last_value()-type function

Tags: business-objects

I need to get the last value associated with a specific ID field in Business Objects. Is there a "last_value()" function in Business Objects, or what is the best way to achieve this?

**InsuredParty**

```
RecID|InsuredID|InsuredName
 1   | 101      | CompanyName1 
 2   | 101      | CompanyName1, LLC 
 3   | 101      | CompanyName1 & Sons, LLC
```

**Policy**

```
RecID|InsuredID|Policy Number
 1   | 101     | ABC 1234567 00 
 2   | 101     | ABC 1234567 01 
 3   | 101     | ABC 1234567 02
```

**Desired Record Output:**

```
InsID|Insured Name              |Policy Number
 101 | CompanyName1 & Sons, LLC | ABC 1234567 00 
 101 | CompanyName1 & Sons, LLC | ABC 1234567 01 
 101 | CompanyName1 & Sons, LLC | ABC 1234567 02
```

**The ultimate report will look like:**

```
Insured Name               Policy Number
 CompanyName1 & Sons, LLC   
                            ABC 1234567 00 
                            ABC 1234567 01 
                            ABC 1234567 02
```

Comment: This blog [post](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/01/get-first-or-last-record-for-id-in-web-intelligence/) and following discussion might prove beneficial for you.

Comment: So you want the "MAX" RecID from InsuredParty and it's name only.  Then join to policy based on the insured Id.  You don't describe how your data exists in teh universe though.  So it's tough to figure out how to accomplish this.  as if the universe has the join on recID and insuredID: i'm not sure how I'd go about this without 2 queries and then merging dimensions making the name an attribute of the insuredID.